# Should I disable "register this connection's addresses in DNS"?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller, nlb

I have DC and aditional DC, both have DNS services and AD replications on. I have configured NLB cluster to used with IIS services on same servers. Problem is that the NLB cluster adress popups up automaticly to DNS as one one servers adresses (server name and clusuter ip). Sometimes there are replication errors etc. sync errors becouse servers dns qeeries goes wrong address (To NLB address). I know it'is not recomeneded to host IIS on DC servers, but...

Should I disable "register this connection's addresses in DNS"? What else there might be happening after disabling that setting on AD scenario etc?

Comment: Please don't ever install NLB and Active Directory on the same server. Or IIS.

Answer (score 4):

Please don't ever install NLB and Active Directory on the same server. Or IIS.

I can't advise you further because having NLB/clustering on an AD domain controller is already untenable.  There's no "best practice" for a bad practice.

If you're still going to do it anyway, then look at [this KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/246804), specifically the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DNS\Parameters\PublishAddresses` registry entry.

You do not want to dynamically publish the NLB VIP.

Comment: The thing we got wrong was that DNS were listening NLB address and autoregisted that to DNS.  We are well known the fact that ad and NLB/IIS should not be hosted on same server, but our scenario with AD is very limited. Previously we have been hosting same kind of NLB/AD/IIS cluster with server 2003 for years without problems with AD.